# Why does a triangular function not work as a radial basis function for interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, radial-basis

This code is based on the example on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_interpolation :

```
def f(x):
    return np.exp(x * np.cos(3 * np.pi * x)) - 1

def rbf_exp(x, epsilon=3):
    return np.exp(-((epsilon * x) ** 2))

# Why doesn't this work?
def rbf_lin(x, epsilon=3):
    return np.maximum(0.0, 1.0 - epsilon * x)

xs = np.arange(15) / 14
xall = np.linspace(0, 1, num=1000)

# Change this to explore RBFs
rbf = rbf_exp
rbfv = np.vectorize(lambda x1, x2: rbf(x1 - x2))

A = rbfv(xs, np.expand_dims(xs, axis=1))
b = f(xs)

# solves `A * w = b` for w
w, _resid, _rank, _s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)

def s(x):
    return np.sum(w * rbf(x - xs))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(11, 8))

axes[0, 0].set_title("Function fit")
axes[0, 0].plot(xall, f(xall), label="Original function")
axes[0, 0].plot(xall, [s(x) for x in xall], label="RBF fit")
axes[0, 0].plot(xs, f(xs), "ok", label="Nodes")
axes[0, 0].legend()

errors = [s(x) - f(x) for x in xall]
axes[1, 0].set_title(f"Fit error (max {np.max(errors):0.3g})")
axes[1, 0].plot(xall, errors, label="error")
axes[1, 0].legend()

axes[0, 1].set_title("RBF")
axes[0, 1].plot(xall, rbf(xall), label="RBF")
axes[0, 1].set_ylim(-0.05, 1.05)
axes[0, 1].legend()

axes[1, 1].set_title("Weights")
axes[1, 1].plot(w, label="weights")
axes[1, 1].legend()
```

It calculates an RBF interpolation of the function `f`:

[image: RBF results and introspection plots using an exponential RBF]

If I use the `rbf_lin` function instead of the `rbf_exp` function, the interpolation fails spectacularly:

[image: RBF results and introspection plots using a broken triangular function]

I'm guessing the triangular function doesn't meet the requirements to be considered an RBF, but I can't figure out why given the description on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function). It's possible I'm not understanding the notation.

Does $\varphi(x) = \hat {\varphi }(\left\|x - c\right\|)$ mean that the Fourier transform of the norm of the function equal the function itself?

#### Edit: bug fixed

I was missing the `abs()` call around the `x` in the `def rbf_lin`. With that, it works:

[image: RBF results and introspection plots using a broken triangular function]

I guess this question should be closed, but the question about interpreting the equation above is still of interest.